# get_entry_list() method with query parameter on sugar crm 7 does not work

Tags: sugarcrm

My code is as below..
Please note that I am trying to retrive all the accounts whose where the Accounts.name='bhagya'. 
The same query workes for me in SugarCRM Version 6.5 (Community edition) but in case of SugarCRM 7 it is not working when I mention query parameter. If I mention 'query'=>'' then I get all the records from the sugarcrm 7 server. It fails when I specify any filter for query parameter. I am using RestAPI - 4.1 
$get_entry_list_parameters = array(

//session id

```
 'session' => $session_id,

 //The name of the module from which to retrieve records

 'module_name' => 'Accounts',

 //The SQL WHERE clause without the word "where".

 //'query' => "Accounts.billing_address_postalcode='60329'",
    //      'query' => "Accounts.name='Ingrid Rofalsky'",
          'query'=>'',

 //The SQL ORDER BY clause without the phrase "order by".

 'order_by' => "",

 //The record offset from which to start.

 'offset' => 0,

 //A list of fields to include in the results.

 'select_fields' => array(
      'id',
      'name',

 ),
 //A list of link names and the fields to be returned for each link name.

 'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(),

 //The maximum number of results to return.

 'max_results' => 10,

 //If deleted records should be included in results.

 'deleted' => 0,

 //If only records marked as favorites should be returned.

 'favorites' => false,
```

);

```
print_r($get_entry_list_parameters);

$get_entry_list_result = call('get_entry_list', $get_entry_list_parameters, $url);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($get_entry_list_result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Can some one help me on this..

Thank you.
Regards
- Bhagya

Comment: What error(s) do you get in the result? Or in your SugarCRM log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the module name to lowercase in query option solved this problem.

I got the answer for my query from below link.
https://community.sugarcrm.com/sugarcrm/topics/get_entry_list_method_with_query_parameter_on_sugar_crm_7_does_not_work?topic-reply-list%5Bsettings%5D%5Bfilter_by%5D=all&topic-reply-list%5Bsettings%5D%5Bpage%5D=1#reply_14588280

Thanks again

Regards
- Bhagya

Answer (score 0):

The Rest API has changed a lot in Sugar7.

The URL for the invokation should look like

> http://servname.com/pro720/rest/v10/Accounts?filter[0][name][$starts]=B&filter[0][email_addresses.email_address]=burgers@example.com&fields=name,account_type,description,email

Where you are filtering the accounts with a name that starts with B, the mail address is burgers@example.com and where you retrieve only the fields name,account_type,description and email

Comment: SugarCRM 7 should still fully support the legacy RESTv4_1 API... all of the legacy APIs, actually. Best practices to use the new stuff, but if you're trying to build support for an existing integration, it shouldn't be too difficult. http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.2/70_API/Web_Services/40_Legacy_REST/SOAP_APIs/